# Java Mock server framework for Samba

Tags: java, mocking, samba, smb

I am trying to write some tests for a Samba client in Java, and need to find a framework that would create a mock Samba server. Something similar to the `Mock FTP Server` for the FTP protocol.

So far I could find only services that would mock a Samba library such as `JCIFS`, but not a Samba server. Is there a framework available for mocking a Samba server?

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but asking for tools/libraries is explicitly off topic here.

Comment: Oh! Is there a separate stack exchange site for such topics?

Comment: There is: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com ... but make sure to **carefully** study their help information to determine if/how to write a request there.

Comment: What about https://www.shellvoide.com/hacks/how-to-setup-rogue-fake-smb-server-to-capture-credentials/ or https://www.hackers-arise.com/create-a-fake-smb-server-with-metas ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But what I'm looking for is a mock samba server that can be started using a Java code, as it can be done using Mock FTP server library.

Comment: I guess you are looking for any SMB server mock, right? Samba is a specific implementation of one. Same way _jcifs_ in a general SMB client, not specifically Samba.

Comment: @Fleur - Did you find one?